# Passing Date to NamedParameterJdbcTemplate in Select query to oracle

Tags: spring, java.util.date

I have a query as below which is returning expected records when run from the SQL Developer

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ( CRT_TS > TO_DATE('25-Aug-2016 15:08:18', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
or UPD_TS > TO_DATE('25-Aug-2016 15:08:18', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

I think that we will not need to apply TO_DATE when we are passing java.util.Date object as date parameters but the below code snippet is silently returning me 0 records.

My SQL query in Java class is as below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ( CRT_TS > :lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp1 
or UPD_TS > :lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp2);
```

The code which executes the above query is as below but the below code snippet is silently returning me 0 records:

```
    parameters.put("lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp1", new java.sql.Date(outputFileMetaData.getLastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp().getTime()));
    parameters.put("lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp2", new java.sql.Date(outputFileMetaData.getLastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp().getTime()));
    list = namedParameterJdbcTemplateOracle.query(sql, parameters, myTabRowMapper);
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you already found the answer but if anybody else needs it, here's what I've found:

`java.sql.Date` doesn't have time, just the date fields. Either use `java.sql.Timestamp` or `java.util.Date`. Both seems to be working for me with `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

Answer (score 4):

A little variation to above solution can be when your input(lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp1/lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp2) is a String instead of Date/TimeStamp (which is what i was looking for and found at [this](https://justinjohnson.org/java/inserting-datetime-with-spring-jdbctemplate-and-namedparameterjdbctemplate/) link -> may be it can help someone):

```
MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
parameters.addValue("lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp1", lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp1, Types.TIMESTAMP);
parameters.addValue("lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp2", lastSuccessfulReplicationTimeStamp2, Types.TIMESTAMP);

list = namedParameterJdbcTemplateOracle.query(sql, parameters, myTabRowMapper);
```

Answer (score 0):

great concise answers by JavaTec & S0m30n3

wanted to share an alternative using a `java.util.Date` that has been formatted as a  `String` in the following date & time format

```java
Date date = new Date();
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(date);
```

in case anyone might need this